# How to order 1,2,3 not 1, 10, 11, 12 in mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

The following code outputs in order of 1, 10, 11, 12 of id.

I want to make it 1,2,3,4...

Could anyone tell me what I should do please.

```
$Q = $this->db->query('SELECT P.*, C.Name AS CatName FROM products AS P LEFT JOIN categories C ON C.id = P.category_id');
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm assuming you've tried the (obvious) addition of `ORDER BY P.id` to the query?

Answer (score 80):

First, add an order by clause at the end:

```
ORDER BY category_id
```

If category_id is a string, then you must treat it like an integer. There are a few ways to do this. I usually add a zero. You can also cast it.

```
ORDER BY category_id + 0
```

Comment: "category_id" should obviously be whichever field you want to sort by.

Answer (score 23):

As previously mentioned MySQL doesn't support alphanumeric sorting. One common trick to solve this is to first order by length:

```
ORDER BY LENGTH(column_name), column_name
```

As long as the non-numeric part of the value is the same length, this will sort 1 before 10, 10 before 100, etc.

Comment: This solved my issue with ORDER BY 'role' column:
'telemarketer1', 'telemarketer10', 'telemarketer2'

Answer (score 14):

You can do an explicit cast by doing:

```
ORDER BY CAST(category_id AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```

But you should reconsider you database layout as a field containing only numeric values should also be of an numeric type..

Best wishes,
Fabian

Comment: this also helped me with SQLite, where - for some reason - a REAL column didn't sort numerically.

Comment: Much appreciate this answer, I never had the issue before since I use INT fields and such BUT I was using a MYSQL function for getting months from a date field and I realized it was not sorting correctly

Answer (score 6):

Make sure that the column that holds 1,2,3,4 is `INT` type, if it is TEXT, you will not get numerical order, but what you describe 1, 10, 11, 2, 22, 23, 31, etc;

And like others mentioned, use `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

**Order by**  only working for numerical values(*int*), not work for *varchar, char*

Your category_id should numerical, otherwise you need to cast values to numerical.

Answer (score -2):

Well, you're not setting any `ORDER BY` clause.