# Sorting numerically get order as 1,2,3 not 1, 10, 11, 12 in Django Python

Tags: python, django

In reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833077/how-to-order-1-2-3-not-1-10-11-12-in-mysql) for mysql ,I tried the following in my Django code

```
myQuery.order_by('myColumn+0')


myQuery.order_by('myColumn'+0)
```

but none worked for me

Comment: This is how [lexicographical ordering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) works...

Comment: @ppeterka66 Yes i know this but I want to cope it !! if it is possible in mysql then there must be some way in django too

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969348/django-ordering-numerical-value-with-order-by

Comment: Ensure the output from the database is numerical data and not strings.

Comment: @ppeterka66 thnq so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well found the solution thanks to ppeterka 66

```
myQuery.filter().extra(
    select={'myinteger': 'CAST(mycharfield AS UNSIGNED)'}
).order_by('myinteger')
```

I used UNSIGNED instead of INTEGER, I guess my mysql doesnot support it