# MySQL sorting with alphanumeric prefix

Tags: mysql, sorting, columnsorting

I've got a database with a column that contains the following data:

```
aaa-1
aaa-2
aaa-3
...
aaa-10
aaa-11
...
aaa-100
aaa-101
...
aaa-1000
```

When I query and sort the data in ascending order, I get:

```
aaa-1
aaa-10
aaa-11
...
aaa-100
aaa-101
...
aaa-1000
...
aaa-2
...
aaa-3
```

Is this actually the correct (machine) way of sorting? Is the order being screwed up because of the `aaa-` prefix? How do I go about sorting this the way a human would (ie something that looks like the first snippet)?

P.S. If the problem does lie in the prefix, is there a way to remove it and sort with just the numeric component?

P.P.S. It's been suggested to me that I should just change my data and add leading zeroes like `aaa-0001` and `aaa-0002`, etc. However, I'm loathe to go that method as each time the list goes up an order of 10, I'd have to reformat this column.

Thank you all in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the number part, convert it to numeric data type and then do an `ORDER BY`:

```
SELECT mytable.*,
    CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycolumn, '-', - 1) AS UNSIGNED) mycolumnintdata
FROM
    mytable
ORDER BY mycolumnintdata;
```

If there are expressions which does not match number, the `CAST` function would return `0` and those records would be displayed first. You may handle this separately if needed.

Comment: Thanks! This did it for me :)

Comment: That's cool @doraemond! Thanks for accepting the answer. Happy programming!

Comment: @James Jithin It works well for me. But unfortunately i need it in a prepared statement to join with my other queries which is already in prepared statement format. I got stuck in the bind_result "Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields..."

Comment: @James Jithin As I was preparing the code, i actually found the answer. The solution is to add another variable in the bind_result (x,x,x,$mycolumnintdata). Thanks for asking. Without you asking, i wouldn't have found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and the trick that did it for me was this one

*"ORDER BY LENGTH(column_name), column_name

As long as the non-numeric part of the value is the same length, this will sort 1 before 10, 10 before 100, etc."*

as given by [Andreas Bergström](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1202214/andreas-bergstr%C3%B6m) on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1833077/how-to-order-1-2-3-not-1-10-11-12-in-mysql/1833095).

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you a sample sorting. Not based on your data sample, but this could help you out.

Say you have data like this :

```
id
----
1
2
6
10
13
```

when you do `ORDER BY id ASC` would return :

```
id
----
1
10
13
2
6
```

I suggest, use `LPAD`.
This query : `SELECT LPAD('12',5,'0')` return `00012`

So when you have table data like I provide above, you can sort them like this :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE
ORDER BY LPAD(ID,7,'0') ASC
```

Based on your data.
`SELECT SUBSTR('aaa-100',5,LENGTH('aaa-100') - 3)` return 100
So, `SELECT LPAD( SUBSTR('aaa-100',5,LENGTH('aaa-100') - 3), 7, '0')` return `00000100`

So you can combine string function such as `SUBSTR` and `LPAD`. Do have any clue now?

Comment: In your example, wouldn't that column sort correctly even without the use of `LDAP` since it's just numerical data?

Comment: Yeah, I understand now how LPAD works, thank you! I wonder, though, whether using your method or James' method works faster.

Answer (score 0):

this is the alphabetical order,
you want numerical order,
for do this you must in the ORDER BY clause

1. trim the costant "aaa-" part
2. convert it in number

   convert(SUBSTRING(val, 3), integer)

Comment: I see now that the column is a string and is treated as such. Thus, shorter strings will get sorted first. Is this really a limitation of database in that it doesn't really have a deep understanding of the information it contains?